# Google Sign In (GSI) after 10 seconds throws a 401

Tags: javascript, google-signin

The behavior can be seen on both our [website](https://hireproof.io/), and [slack](https://slack.com/).  It looks like it tries to hit this endpoint:

```
curl 'https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true&authuser=0' \
  -H 'authority: play.google.com' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'authorization: SAPISIDHASH da3120fd2c8773cb248175715b41c00a9ffc7d3c' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'origin: https://accounts.google.com' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-client-data: CI+2yQEIprbJAQjEtskBCKmdygEIlKHLAQikvMwBCNS8zAE=' \
  -H 'x-goog-authuser: 0' \
  --data-raw '[[1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,"en"]],1112,[["1662800548756",null,[],null,null,null,null,"[\"xpq/7NvyMfFVPEXdvMHbBA\",12,false,null,\"178803201798-pfac5tu091grgjs5hu9a4djeor0vqrel.apps.googleusercontent.com\",\"https://hireproof.io\",[2],null,null,null,null,null,null,5,null,null,null,[1,1,1,null,3,1,1]]",null,null,12,null,null,null,-7200,null,null,null,null,[],1,null,null,null,null,null,[]]],"1662800558756",[]]' \
  --compressed
```

The play.google.com appears to be an android endpoint for logging.  This is not causing any issues other than an annoyance that it's causing console logging an error on production.  Has anyone seen this or know a fix?

Comment: Same issue with my Google Sign In button.  Additionally, about 10 seconds after this, it sends another post request to: https://play.google.com/log?hasfast=true&auth=[...] and encounters the same 401 result